# how to create a .condarc file for Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, proxy, anaconda, conda

I am trying to set up a proxy server in Anaconda because my firewall does not allow me to run online commands such as

> conda update

I see online that I should create a **.condarc** file that contains the proxy address. Unfortunately,

1. I dont know how to create that file (is it a text file?)
2. and where to put it?! (in which folder? in the Anaconda folder?)

Any help appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a text (YAML) file that goes in the home directory, or optionally, the root of the anaconda installation.

The contents should look like

```
# Proxy settings: http://[username]:[password]@[server]:[port]
proxy_servers:
    http: http://user:pass@corp.com:8080
    https: https://user:pass@corp.com:8080
```

See http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There are chances that the .condarc file is hidden as was in my case. I was using Linux Mint (Sarah) and couldn't find the file though later on I found that it was hidden in the home directory and hence when I opted to show hidden files I could find it.

Answer (score 2):

to create the .condarc file open Anaconda Prompt and type:

conda config

it will appear in your user's home directory