# Conda hangs when installing from https://conda.anaconda.org

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I'm having a problem when I try to install packages from https://conda.anaconda.org. When I try for example 'conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/IOOS rtree', it shows the dependencies it is going to install, but when I accept, it gets stuck in 'Fetching packages ...'  .I thought that the problem was that I am behind my company proxy, but when I check my proxy settings I get:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh.exe winhttp show proxy
gets
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

So it seems I'm not behind a proxy. I am using Anaconda 2.4.0 in Windows 7.

Does anyone how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar problem with conda.
Even though I had done appropriate settings in environment variables
for my proxy servers, conda install hanged.

I used the netsh command that you used :

```
C:\Users\tauseef>netsh.exe winhttp show proxy

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

I see it does not return a proxy server but indeed i know for sure
that my system was behind a proxy server.

So, I created a .condarc file ( as mentioned here : [how to create a .condarc file for Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896309/how-to-create-a-condarc-file-for-anaconda))
in my home directory on Windows7 ( C:\Users\tauseef)
You can use the following command to create a very minimal looking .condarc file (see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1757):

```
conda config --add channels r
```

and I entered the following lines on .condarc file

```
# Proxy settings: http://[username]:[password]@[server]:[port]
proxy_servers:
    http: http://ef.fake.company.com:8080
    https: https://ef.fake.company.com:8080
```

Now I am able to install a package (say mingw) using

```
conda install mingw
```

Comment: wait... I know this might be a dumb question but comming from someone who knows absolutely nothing about proxy servers: do I actually use this http://ef.fake.company.com or do I have to change it with something else?

Answer (score 7):

I was having a similar issue on an Ubuntu server. After running the following command, I was able to use conda install:

```
conda clean --all
```